# Raspberry pi flashing LED issue - Python vs Java

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi

i am trying to make an LED light flash on the raspberry pi using some code i found online ( i know - not the best but it was a tutorial site)

When i run the following python code the led light flashes;

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
pinNum = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #numbering scheme that corresponds to breakout board and pin layout
GPIO.setup(pinNum,GPIO.OUT) #replace pinNum with whatever pin you used, this sets up that pin as an output
#set LED to flash forever
while True:
  GPIO.output(pinNum,GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  GPIO.output(pinNum,GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

When i run the following Java code which is supposed to do the same - all i get to the console are the print statements which i have added - no flashing light

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;  
 import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;  
 import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;  
 import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;  
 import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;  

 public class ControlGpioExample {  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
     final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();  
     final GpioPinDigitalOutput ledPin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin
.GPIO_04, "MyLED", PinState.LOW);  
     System.out.println("Started");
     try  
     {  
       while(true)  
       {
         System.out.println(ledPin==null);
         System.out.println("Looping pin now"); 
         ledPin.high();
         System.out.println("Set high called");  
         Thread.sleep(2000);  
         ledPin.low();  
         System.out.println("Set low called");
         Thread.sleep(2000);  
       }  
     }  
     catch(Exception ex)  
     {  
       gpio.shutdown();  
       ex.printStackTrace();  
     }  
   }  
 }
```

Does anyone know why this might be? I think logically the should be doing the same thing - both are using the same GPIO pin number from the pi too

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure both pins map to the same 'physical' pin? The diagram under the 'pin numbering' header here http://pi4j.com/usage.html seems to have them enumerated differently than the design specification. Given that the operations succeed I'd consider it likely that you're not using the correct pin index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that your pin numbers might be off. Since the java code does not throw exceptions, I'd consider it likely that one of the pins is activated, but which has a different index than the one your LED is connected to.

The documentation of Pi4J lists this table for pin number reference: https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/pins/

Your python code uses the BCM index mode, whose port mappings are listed in the table. In this case, the BCM port 4 maps to GPIO_7 in Pi4j instead of the GPIO_4 you use in your java code.

Answer (score 11):

The GPIO_4 in the Python GPIO code corresponds to this diagram

[image]

The pi4j corresponds to the diagram below

[image]

So GPIO_04 is in a completely different location! You should change the java code to use GPIO_07

[Here's an explanation](http://wiringpi.com/pins/) of why wiringpi has different names for the pins. It's very confusing that they are both using GPIO_XX

Comment: Just wondering: why are you providing an additional answer to this question that is exactly the same as the one already there?

Comment: @Bartvbl, well the notice says "This question has not received enough attention." so I just gave it some more attention. At least 2 people found it useful.

Comment: Ah, I thought that meant it needed more views.